# Newtonsoft.Json Deserialize big file to objects (with lists) c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a JSON file that looks like this...

```
 [
          {  
             "words":[  
                "test1",
                "test2,
             ],
             "id":50,

          },
          {  
             "words":[  
                "test1",
                "test2",
                "test3",
             ],
             "id":25,
          }
       ]
```

And I want to Deserialize this in to the following object...
I have made 2 classes that I want to use...

```
public class Record
  {
    private List<Word> Words { get; set;  }
    private int Id { get; set; }
  }



public class Word
  {
    private String Tekst;

    public Word(string tekst)
    {
      Tekst = tekst;
    }
  }
```

I tried some many things, but I always get errors like that It can't be put in the word list and stuff like that.

Is it possible to use the Newtonsoft.Json to achieve this?

Please help me out guys

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "annouri" to type 'PB.Domain.Words'. Path '[0].words[0]', line 1, position 37.'

Comment: @ThomasVerhoeven your JSON is not valid. Have you checked it out using a JSON Validator of some sort? For Example: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model should be

```
public class Record
{
    public List<string> Words { set; get; }
    public long Id { set; get; }

}
public class AllRecords
{
    public List<Record> Records { set; get; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize as

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllRecords>(yourjson);
```

**EDIT - for your new Json**

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Record>>(yourjson);
```

Comment: No I can't use it like that because I want to write it to a database later on so it should be a list of words....

Comment: @ThomasVerhoeven But it is  (according to your json) not a list of words, it is a list of strings. After using this model you can write code to convert it to any type you want

Comment: I'm going to test it right now, I let you know! Thanks xD

Comment: I get this: 

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'PB.Domain.JCLASS' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: @ThomasVerhoeven I used *your json in question* and it works. It seems your json in question in the real one differ.... Without knowing your json it is hard to say anything (BTW: I added a `"` after `"test2` to make it a valid json)

Comment: I changed my JSON would you still do it like you did before?

Comment: @ThomasVerhoeven This works if you correct the JSON you listed in your question. As it's currently invalid. I corrected it in your question it's awaiting peer review.

Comment: @ThomasVerhoeven I updated my answer. But please note that our time is as valuable as yours. So post a correct question next time

Comment: I'm using it as a file...is that a problem? I can't check it as correct if it isn't working for me, I'm sorry..

Comment: @ThomasVerhoeven but you post the json correctly, right? BTW: json is a  string. It is not important whereever you get it from